# Can AppInit_DLLs be used to hook APIs from Ws2_32.dll?

Tags: c++, winapi, hook, winsock, winsock2

I'm looking for ways to redirect the outbound TCP/IP connections from a specific port on a Windows client to a different port number. (This is needed to provide a capability to redirect SMB connections from the port 445 that is used for file and printer sharing.)

I can't find a way to do it other than hook the WinSock APIs and change the port there. I found [AppInit_DLLs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd744762%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) technique and I'm wondering if it can be used to hook Ws2_32.dll (that seems to house WinSock APIs)?

My thinking was to then hook to [connect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms737625%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [accept](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms737526%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) APIs that normally set the port number. It's all just a thought so I'd appreciate someone's take on this before I can actually jump into coding it...

Comment: These kind of shenanigans tend to attract the attention of virus scanners.

Answer (score 1):

Why not? Yes it's possible, but do not forget to load the DLL before hooking. Since AppInit gets loaded when user32.dll loads (and it's surely before loading ws2_32).

Have a look at detours, or try to make an own inline hook. Please be careful with muti-threaded applications, you have to use multithread-safe hooks.

Comment: Not all processes load user32, and most SMB traffic is initiated from kernel mode, not user mode.

Comment: If it's initiated from kernel mode, then he can't do anything against it (except a driver, but that's not too likely). I assumed he at least tested it with injected his code into another process.

Comment: Applications that access network resources typically just use `CreateFile` and `ReadFile`, and let the kernel do the redirection. Applications typically do not open ports and send raw SMB packets back and forth.

Comment: Yes, I agree with Raymond. It is on the level lower than user32.dll. So no luck there...

Answer (score -2):

Unfortunately, this isn't possible. Your best bet is to make a proxy DLL, replacing the custom methods you wish to hook with your own.